# Como pegar a distância da barra de rolagem para o topo da página no Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Nos outros navegadores consigo através do

```
$(document).scrollTop();
```

Mas no IE isso sempre retorna 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo essa [resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2717252/1608936) pode-se fazer assim:

```js
var top = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || 
    document.body.scrollTop;
```